# C# Lookup ptimisation suggestion are welcome

Tags: c#, linq, ilookup

I have the code below which works for the purpose of what I need but I have an idea that it could be made faster. Please let me know if this code can be improved in any way...

The main issue is that I need to query "data" several time. I just need to make sure that there is no shortcut that I could have used instead.

```
data= GetData()// this return ILookup<Tuple(string, string, string),string>
foreach (var v0 in data)
{
    if (v0.Key.Item3 == string.Empty)
    {
        //Get all related data
        var tr_line = data[v0.Key];
        sb.AppendLine(tr_line.First());

        foreach (var v1 in data)
        {
            if (v1.Key.Item2 == string.Empty && v1.Key.Item1 == v0.Key.Item1)
            {
                var hh_line = data[v1.Key];
                sb.AppendLine(hh_line.First());

                foreach (var v2 in data)
                {
                    if (v2.Key.Item1 == v0.Key.Item1 && v2.Key.Item2 != string.Empty && v2.Key.Item3 != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var hl_sl_lines = data[v2.Key].OrderByDescending(r => r);
                        foreach (var v3 in hl_sl_lines)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(v3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What type does `GetData` return? An array of `IGrouping` or a Dictionary?

Comment: Please describe what you need the code to do; just dumping a wall of code out there and asking "can it be better?" is not likely to get you what you want.

Comment: You sure about that return type for `GetData()`? As my environment doesn't like `v0.Key`

Comment: How much time does it take to execute now?

Comment: Well, i have no performance issue as such... This is just to know if i'm not using any nice feature that i could have used to retrieve related hierarchical data.

Comment: "Please let me know if this code can be improved in any way..." - if this example hasn't been sanitised for SO I strongly recommend choosing more meaningful names for variables and properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neater, more linq:

```
        var data = GetData();

        foreach (var v0 in data)
        {
            if (v0.Key.Item3 != string.Empty) continue;

            //Get all related data 
            var tr_line = data[v0.Key];
            sb.AppendLine(tr_line.First());

            var hhLines = from v1 in data
                          where v1.Key.Item2 == string.Empty &&
                                v1.Key.Item1 == v0.Key.Item1
                          select data[v1.Key];

            foreach (var hh_line in hhLines)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(hh_line.First());

                var grouping = v0;
                var enumerable = from v2 in data
                                 where v2.Key.Item1 == grouping.Key.Item1 &&
                                       v2.Key.Item2 != string.Empty &&
                                       v2.Key.Item3 != string.Empty
                                 select data[v2.Key].OrderByDescending(r => r)
                                 into hl_sl_lines from v3 in hl_sl_lines select v3;

                foreach (var v3 in enumerable)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(v3);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, this looks indeed more neat but it turned out to be twice as slow as my orginal code.

Comment: Please discard Well, this looks indeed more neat and more Linq. More testing revealed no major difference in speed. Many thanks for the great insight in linq and c#.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to avoid using Tuple for this kind of code, because, even to you, a few months from now, this code will be incomprehensible. Make a class, or even better, an immutable struct with the correct property names. Even the fastest code is worthless if it is not maintainable.

That said, you have three nested loops that iterate the same collection. It would be plausible that a sorted collection will perform faster, as you will need to compare only with adjacent items.

Please try to explain what you are trying to accomplish, so someone would try to offer more specific help.

Comment: I have a complex CSV file. I use linq to retreive the line of the file and querry these lines. The result is then stored in a lookup object (GetData()). This file contains several records of different type. Some records starts with HH, other starts with HL and so on... But to comply to the formats, they(lines) need to appear in a certain order. The hierarchy needed is best described by the code that i have written above.